# How to get/calculate margin width of grouped UITableView on iPad or iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview

I have a grouped table view that I use to display several properties of a model. Those properties can be longish so I calculate the height of the cells in `tableView:heightForCellAtIndexPath:` using `NSString's` `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` method. I'm now making the app universal so I need to pass correct cell width to this method. And I can't simply use `tableView's` width as it's "margins" are much wider on iPad.

The second issue with those margins I have, is that I have a custom `UIView` for section in that `tableView` and I wan't to align it's contents with cells contents.

So the question is: how do I get or calculate the width of margins in a grouped `UITableView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can SET width instead of calculating something like that

```
CGSize constraintSize;
constraintSize.height = CGFLOAT_MAX;

if (isItIpad)
constraintSize.width = 500.0f;
else if (group=1)
constraintSize.width = 250.0f;
end if
```

and use it in your sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:

or you can calculate max (or min) width in the group (sizeWithFont:) and use it

Comment: And that's probably what I'll do. Even though I'd prefer no to use fixed numbers and be a little bit more flexible. Thanks!

Comment: I have been looking for an answer to this and haven't found one, for now I'm stuck using fixed numbers like in the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following in my app (it also supports orientation change):

`CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width - 40.0f, MAXFLOAT);`